# how to play video wmv format in electron app?

Tags: html, electron, wmv

I'm going to build a desktop app by electron that show my video files. my videos are wmv format.html5 dose not support the format.
How can I play my videos? Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you find a solution but change the format is the best solution.